# ¿Que puedo hacer para que no se pueda escribir sobre un Combobox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

lo que quiero decir es que al seleccionar un item del combobox como se ve en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no haya la posibilidad de que se pueda escribir o sobrescribir en el combobox como se muestra en esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El combo tiene 3 modos.. en 1 de ellos, no te deja escribir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comboBox tiene 3 posibilidades de selección de estilo en la propiedad DropDownStyle:

> 1. Simple: en este modo admitirá entradas por teclado sin la posibilidad de desplegar la lista, pudiendo navegar entre los items con la flecha hacia abajo del teclado
> 2. DropDown : en este modo puedes seleccionar los items de la lista desplegable y acepta entrada del usuario en el teclado para modificar los items.
> 3. DropDownList: en este modo puedes seleccionar los items de la lista desplegable y no acepta la entrada del teclado para modificar los items.

Por lo tanto para obtener la funcionalidad que deseas deberás modificar la propiedad del ComboBox DropDownStyle a DropDownList:

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```